# Indice fuera de intervalo en C#

Tags: c#, .net

seguramente me van a cortar una o restarme puntos pero no importa no encuentro el error jajaja.

También ya leí las preguntas planteadas acá que son similares.

Les comento, con este código lo que hago es generar listas para la fecha_legalizacion y así.

Creo lo mismo pero tipo get; set;

inicio una variable x en 0;

busco datos desde un procedimiento almacenado y voy asignando a cada lista el valor del reader, y al final a este valor de X lo voy aumentando.

Después genero una lista, inicio una variable en cero y aplico un while, creo un nuevo item para la lista y al final el valor de i lo aumento.

Tengo la misma estructura para buscar otro montón de datos y me funciona bien pero para este caso no sé en qué está fallando.

si alguien me puede iluminar se lo agradecería.

Como dato: actualmente mi procedimiento me trae de vuelta una fila de datos.

Gracias

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class DatosComplementarios
    {

        //las listas para guardar losd datos
        public static List<string> fecha_legalizacion = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> legalizacion_numero = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> visacion_numero = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> visacion_fecha = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> tipo_operacion_codigo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> presentacion_zona_franca_codigo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> presentacion_aduana_codigo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> origen_aduana_codigo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> usuario_nombre = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> usuario_direccion = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> usuario_correo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> usuario_contrato_numero = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> usuario_rut_numero = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> usuario_rut_dv = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> representante_tipo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> representante_codigo = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> representante_rut = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> representante_rut_dv = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> representante_nombre = new List<string>();

        //las variables de donde voy a tomar los datos
        public string ifecha_legalizacion { get; set; }
        public string ilegalizacion_numero { get; set; }
        public string ivisacion_numero { get; set; }
        public string ivisacion_fecha { get; set; }
        public string itipo_operacion_codigo { get; set; }
        public string ipresentacion_zona_franca_codigo { get; set; }
        public string ipresentacion_aduana_codigo { get; set; }
        public string iorigen_aduana_codigo { get; set; }
        public string iusuario_nombre { get; set; }
        public string iusuario_direccion { get;set;}        
        public string iusuario_correo { get;set;}
        public string iusuario_contrato_numero { get;set;}
        public string iusuario_rut_numero {get;set;}
        public string iusuario_rut_dv { get;set;}
        public string irepresentante_tipo { get;set;}
        public string irepresentante_codigo { get;set;}
        public string irepresentante_rut { get;set;}
        public string irepresentante_rut_dv { get;set;}
        public string irepresentante_nombre { get;set;}

        //contador
        public static int x = 0;
        static SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();

        public static void AbrirConexion()
        {
            conexion.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=xxx.xx.xx.xx; Initial Catalog=terra; user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxx";
            conexion.Open();
        }

        public static void CerrarConexion()
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }


        public static void ObtenerDatosIngreso(int Ndoc, int Cdoc)
        {
            AbrirConexion();
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "Sp_c_XML_ZF_Declaracion 'C'," + Ndoc + "," + Cdoc;

            var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //los elementos que se rescatan de la base de datos a través del procedimiento almacenado
                fecha_legalizacion.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                legalizacion_numero.Add(reader[1].ToString());
                visacion_numero.Add(reader[2].ToString());
                visacion_fecha.Add(reader[3].ToString());
                tipo_operacion_codigo.Add(reader[4].ToString());
                presentacion_zona_franca_codigo.Add(reader[5].ToString());
                presentacion_aduana_codigo.Add(reader[6].ToString());
                origen_aduana_codigo.Add(reader[7].ToString());
                usuario_nombre.Add(reader[8].ToString());
                usuario_correo.Add(reader[9].ToString());
                usuario_contrato_numero.Add(reader[10].ToString());
                usuario_rut_numero.Add(reader[11].ToString());
                usuario_rut_dv.Add(reader[12].ToString());
                representante_tipo.Add(reader[13].ToString());
                representante_codigo.Add(reader[14].ToString());
                representante_rut.Add(reader[15].ToString());
                representante_rut_dv.Add(reader[16].ToString());
                representante_nombre.Add(reader[17].ToString());
                x++;
            }
            reader.Close();
            CerrarConexion(); // cierro la conexion
        }

        public static List<DatosComplementarios> GetDatosComplementarios(int Ndoc, int Cdoc)
        {
            ObtenerDatosIngreso(Ndoc, Cdoc);

            List<DatosComplementarios> ListaDatosComplementarios = new List<DatosComplementarios>();

            int i = 0;
            while (i <= x - 1)
            {
                ListaDatosComplementarios.Add(new DatosComplementarios() {
                                            ifecha_legalizacion = fecha_legalizacion[i],
                                            ilegalizacion_numero = legalizacion_numero[i],
                                            ivisacion_numero = visacion_numero[i],
                                            ivisacion_fecha = visacion_fecha[i],
                                            itipo_operacion_codigo = tipo_operacion_codigo[i],
                                            ipresentacion_zona_franca_codigo = presentacion_zona_franca_codigo[i],
                                            ipresentacion_aduana_codigo = presentacion_aduana_codigo[i],
                                            iorigen_aduana_codigo = origen_aduana_codigo[i],
                                            iusuario_nombre = usuario_nombre[i],
                                            iusuario_direccion = usuario_direccion[i],
                                            iusuario_correo = usuario_correo[i],
                                            iusuario_contrato_numero = usuario_contrato_numero[i],
                                            iusuario_rut_numero = usuario_rut_numero[i],
                                            iusuario_rut_dv = usuario_rut_dv[i],
                                            irepresentante_tipo = representante_tipo[i],
                                            irepresentante_codigo = representante_codigo[i],
                                            irepresentante_rut = representante_rut[i],
                                            irepresentante_rut_dv = representante_rut_dv[i],
                                            irepresentante_nombre = representante_nombre[i]
                });
                i++;
            }

            return ListaDatosComplementarios;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el método **`ObtenerDatosIngreso`** nunca rellenas la lista **`usuario_direccion`** por eso cuando pasas al método **`GetDatosComplementarios`** té salta el error fuera de índice, ya que la lista esta vacía.

Agrega dentro de tu método ***`ObtenerDatosIngreso`*** la siguiente línea:

```
usuario_direccion.Add(reader[indice].ToString());
```

Otra cosa, que pasaría si algunos de los valores vendrían nulos... Exacto no podrías hacerle un ***`ToString`***
por lo que te arrojara una excepción de ***`NullPointerException`***

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!